# Setting source of an Image control from Memory Stream using Non-UI thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, live-streaming, fingerprint

I am Capturing image from a finger print Scanner and i want to display the captured image live in an Image control.

```
//Onclick of a Button
 Thread WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureThread));
 WorkerThread.Start();
```

So i created a thread as above and called the method that captures the image from the device and sets the source of the Image control as follows.

```
private void CaptureThread()
    {
        m_bScanning = true;
        while (!m_bCancelOperation)
        {
            GetFrame();
            if (m_Frame != null)
            {

                    MyBitmapFile myFile = new MyBitmapFile(m_hDevice.ImageSize.Width, m_hDevice.ImageSize.Height, m_Frame);
                    MemoryStream BmpStream = new MemoryStream(myFile.BitmatFileData);
                    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                    imageSource.BeginInit();
                    imageSource.StreamSource = BmpStream;
                    imageSource.EndInit();
                    if (imgLivePic.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    {
                        imgLivePic.Source = imageSource;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Action act = () => { imgLivePic.Source = imageSource; };
                        imgLivePic.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act);
                    }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        m_bScanning = false;
    }
```

Now when i Run the project it throws an Exception on line `Action act = () => { imgLivePic.Source = imageSource; };` Saying "**The Calling thread Can Not Access this object because a different thread owns it**".
i did some research and i found out that if i want to use UI controls over a NON-UI thread i should use Dispatcher.Invoke method, which as you can see i have but i am still getting the same exception.
can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use dispatcher

Comment: @Gun thanks for the reply but as you can see in the code i have used dispatcher its still throwing the same exception. and as far as i have checked the way i used the dispatcher also seems right, no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BitmapImage does not necessarily need to be created in the UI thread. If you `Freeze` it, it will later be accessible from the UI thread. Thus you will also reduce the resource consumption of your application. In general, you should try to freeze all Freezables if possible, especially bitmaps.

```
using (var bmpStream = new MemoryStream(myFile.BitmatFileData))
{
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.StreamSource = bmpStream;
    imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imageSource.EndInit();
}

imageSource.Freeze(); // here

if (imgLivePic.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    imgLivePic.Source = imageSource;
}
else
{
    Action act = () => { imgLivePic.Source = imageSource; };
    imgLivePic.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @clemens it solved the above problem and another problem that i had not mentioned so i marked your answer as true.

Answer (score 0):

The `BitmapImage` itself needs to be constructed on the `Dispatcher` thread.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. it seems that it did the job. (p.s i have been away from here can u help vote up the question so i can get enough reputation to vote up your answer?) thanks

Comment: This is not true. The BitmapImage can well be created on a non-UI thread, as long as it is frozen before being accessed from the UI thread. See my answer.

Comment: @clemens but i cant afford to freeze the BitmapImage as i am showing the images captured from the device live in Image control, so we are talking about 10's of frames being passed in a second so freezing will slow it down. thanks anyway

Comment: @FaisalMalikyar You are creating a new BitmapImage for each frame, which can well be frozen. Freezing won't cost any time. On the contrary, it will probably reduce memory consumption end thus improve overall performance of your application. There is generally no need for a BitmapImage not to be frozen after EndInit, because you can't modify it anyway. The reason that EndInit does not already freeze the BitmapImage is that downloading may still be in progress.